# I got Undefined index: reading recursively an array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, laravel, undefined

I'm going to be crazy, I can't understand what is the problem.

I have this array:

```
array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["parent_id"]=>
        NULL
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Events"
        ["children"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(3) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(1) "2"
            ["parent_id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["name"]=>
            string(9) "Concerts"
          }
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["parent_id"]=>
        NULL
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Music"
        ["children"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(3) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(1) "5"
            ["parent_id"]=>
            string(1) "4"
            ["name"]=>
            string(4) "Rock"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and I try to print with this recursive function:

```
public function printTree($tree) {
    $result = "";
    if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) {
        $result .= '<ul>';
        foreach($tree as $node) {
            $result .= '<li>Cat: '.$node['name'];
                $subtree = array($node['children']);
                $this->printTree($subtree);
            $result .= '</li>';
        }
        $result .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I get an "Undefined index: name" error.
Do I need to declare name? how?
Is the array with incorrect syntax?

If I comment the recursive call

```
$subtree = array($node['children']);
$this->printTree($subtree);,
```

then `$node['name']` isn't undefined and the code works, but of course with only with one level of depth.

SOLVED: (Thanks all guys!)

```
public function printTree($tree) {
    $result = "";
    if(is_array($tree) && count($tree) > 0) {
        $result .= '<ul>';
        foreach($tree as $node) {
            $result .= '<li>Cat: '.$node['name'];
                if (isset($node['children'])) { 
                    $result .= $this->printTree($node['children']);
                }
            $result .= '</li>';
        }
        $result .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Use `var_dump` or `print_r` right before your line `$result.= '<li>Cat: ' . $node['name'];`.  It will tell you the contents of the $node, and you will be able to see where / why it's throwing the NOTICE (not error).

Comment: can you point to the line of code where you are getting the undefined index error ?

Comment: **if I use var_dump I get the undefined index Notica, but laravel allow me to do dd(); the content of $node is:** 
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["parent_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "Events"
  ["children"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "Concert"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "Parties"
    }
  }
}
**and of $nodo['name']** 
string(7) "Events"

Comment: The Notice line is: **$result .= '<li>Cat: '.$nodo['name'];**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing `$node['children']` into an additional array. That way you are not dealing with the subarray of this node (which has a name later on), but you have another layer of array.

Skip this array layer, remove it.

Also note that `!is_null()` isn't really a nice check if you then want to use that variable as an array. Check for `is_array()` instead, because strings and other scalar values will return `count>0` as well - they return 1. Only NULL returns count=0.

Comment: OK, It's true but now I get Undefined index: children. I change the code to directly: **$this->printTree($nodo['children']);**  Like this I don't have a new layer but the $nodo['children'] is undefined at this line. :(

Comment: Yes, because you are not checking if you actually have another level of children. Only call the function again if you have. `if (isset($node['children'])) { $this->printTree...`

Comment: Sven, you are a wonderful guy! It works. I was trying `if ($node['children'])` w/o `isset` because I understud it's the same. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to append the results returned by the consecutive calls to printTree() for child nodes to the $result.

```
$result .= $this->printTree($node['children']);
```

:)

Comment: yeah I saw just now. I came to edit the post and write it fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want to enclose the $subtree-stuff into an if-condition checking for the existence of the key 'children', because as it is now, you have created an infinite loop of recursive calls to `printTree()`, but you only want to do this, if the key 'children' exists.

Second, I guess you want to add `$result .=` in front of `$this->printTree($subtree);`, otherwise the return value will simply be discarded.

Third, don't do `$subtree = array($node['children']);`. `$node['children']` already is an array, so this adds another level to the array, which makes the recursion break.

So, the final function should look something like this:

```
public function printTree($tree) {
    $result = '';
    if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) {
        $result .= '<ul>';
        foreach($tree as $node) {
            $result .= '<li>Cat: '.$node['name'];
            if (isset($node['children'])) {
                $subtree = $node['children'];
                $result .= $this->printTree($subtree);
            }
            $result .= '</li>';
        }
        $result .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Edit:** Whoops, was too slow there, the others also found the three problems here :)